# Prove that $|n-\frac{\sigma_0(n)\phi(n)}{2}|$ equal to a prime implies that n is a semiprime

Tags: prime-numbers, totient-function, divisor-sum

Unfortunately I don't have much to add. The statement appears to be true based on examination of small n. [Menon's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#Menon.27s_identity) gives an alternative respresentation of $\sigma_0(n)\phi(n)$, but I don't know if this is a potential path towards proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true.  Consider $n=255=3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17$.  We have $\sigma_0(n) = 8$ and $\phi(n) = (3-1) \cdot (5 - 1) \cdot (17 - 1) = 128$, so $\vert n - \frac{\sigma_0(n) \phi(n)}{2}\vert = 257$ which is prime.  But $255$ is not a semiprime.

Comment: I see. I thought this might be the case for some larger products of distinct primes. Have you found any counterexamples that aren't squarefree?

Comment: I think there aren't any.  If $n$ has a duplicated factor then we have $\phi(n) = p \cdot (p-1) \cdot x$ for some $x$.  Also since $p$ is a factor of $n$ we have $n = p \cdot y$ for some $y$.  But now $\vert p \cdot y - \frac{p \cdot (p-1) \cdot x \cdot \sigma_0(n)}{2} \vert$ is divisible by $p$.

Comment: Great! Do you see a way to further characterize the values for which the function is prime?

Comment: They have to be composite but aside from that I think there have to be infinitely many even when restricted to k-primes, can't we use Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions?

Comment: if we consider a number $n=p_1p_2...p_k$ with $p_1,...,p_k$ distinct primes, then $\frac{\phi(n)\sigma_0(n)}{2}-n=2^{k-1}(\prod_{i=1}^k(p_i-1))-n$. Is there a way this can be simplified? I'm not sure I see how the values form arithmetic progressions.

Comment: Fix all but one of the primes to different values and what's left is a linear function of the remaining prime whose value also has to be prime.  In other words we have to find $p_k$ such that $a \cdot p_k + b$ is also prime.  Dirichlet's theorem doesn't quite finish the job since it only says there are an infinite number of solutions not an infinite number of prime solutions.